# MS Access VBA to run all saved imports together

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking for a VBA code to run multiple saved imports in MS Access 2010. I used `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "*"` but gave an error.

I know I am doing something wrong here. Please understand I am a newbie to VBA. I have almost 8 saved imports in .csv formats in a specific location. All I want is to automate it through VBA.

Comment: Please provide more details, like what code have you been using and what error was raised, so that others can help out.

Comment: I have created a ms access form with a vba code when I choose an import path, the path inside the Saved Import automatically changes. path is choosen, there is a button called Import in the same form. As the paths are changed, all I have to do now is import the 8 saved imports in the access. Destination tables and source .csv all exists. Now I need a code to just run my saved imports one after another... is there a way to include a simple code for this ?

Answer (score 1):

i guess you have taken all other necessary steps already. 
loop through the saved import/export and execute them one by one. 
something like:

pseudo would be:
loop through the import/export and execute it manually.

in code would be:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.count - 1
    Debug.Print CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name
Next i
```

**EDIT**

Your ImportExportSpecifications details are saved as XML format and you can access that information via

```
CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).XML
```

within the XML you will find the path = "your file.xlsx".  Do a string job to extract the path and validate the file ending and implement your code.

Comment: Hi Krish, it is giving an error message. Please note that I have both xlsx as well as .csv imports saved in Saved Imports, I want only .csv to be choosen. So, can't we give it like -select all from Saved Imports where file type = ".csv"  ?

Comment: check the filepath in the .xml and do your if conditions there.

Comment: Krish, Can you please share the code for the above xml ? I am blank here... please !

Comment: added few more information, now your turn to code it