# VBS Loop Through Accb files in folder and run saves imports/exports

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, automation

Just learning some VBS and struggling a little with how to work a specific command for Access Exports/Imports.

In short, I need to loop through all .accb files in a folder. (I think I have that nailed)
For each of the files found, I need to open the file and run all saved imports, THEN saved exports.

I'll attach my code so far.

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("X:\Path\Path")

For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtentionName(objFile.Name)) = "accb" Then

    'Loop for Opening Access DB and running all imports, then exports
    'Close Access DB


Next


Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

I've not managed to get very far with looping through the saved Imports/Exports in Access though and I've done a power of googling.

I can write each import/export command explicitly, but I'd much rather this script wouldn't have to be updated each time I added a new import or export.

```
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")


objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "Path"

objAccess.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "xxxx"
objAccess.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "yyyy"

objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

ObjAccess.Quit
'Access.Application.Quit
Set ObjAccess = Nothing
```

I think the only way I can force it to run Imports first is via naming standards. 
Lets say each Import/Export has the following naming standard.
I- name
E- name

I think another two For/If loops are required here, but unsure how to go about it.

Any thoughts?

Thank you Andre,

I'll update again when I've managed to test.
But this is what I now have.

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("X:\Path\Path")


For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtentionName(objFile.Name)) = "accb" Then

    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "Path"

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.count - 1
    Debug.Print CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name
    If Left(CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name,2) = "I-" Then
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name

    Next i

    Dim z As Integer
    For z = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.count - 1
    Debug.Print CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name
    If Left(CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name,2) = "-" Then
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name

    Next z

 Set i = Nothing
 Set z = Nothing

    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

    ObjAccess.Quit
    Set ObjAccess = Nothing

Next


Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Update #3 :

Ok, my code currently looks like this.

```
option explicit

dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, Access

Set objShell = CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”)

ScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName

Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ScriptFile = objFSO.GetFile(ScriptPath)

ScriptFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(ScriptFile) 

Set objFolder = ScriptFolder


For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtentionName(objFile.Name)) = "accdb" Then
    Set Access = objFolder & objFile.Name
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase Access

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.count - 1
    Debug.Print CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name
    If Left(CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name,2) = "I-" Then
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name

    Next i

    Dim z As Integer
    For z = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.count - 1
    Debug.Print CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name
    If Left(CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name,2) = "E-" Then
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name

    Next z

 Set i = Nothing
 Set z = Nothing

    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

    ObjAccess.Quit
    Set ObjAccess = Nothing
    Set Access = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing


Next


Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

The intention is to identify the folder the script is in, loop through the .accdb files and run all their imports then exports.
Im getting an error on line 1 and I cant for the life of me figure out why!?!
"Microsoft VBScript compilation error"

Any thoughts?

Alternatively, is there a better way to do this all together?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838811/ms-access-vba-to-run-all-saved-imports-together (?)

Comment: It does, thank you.
I don't know why that didn't come up in my search.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do I pass my objFile to the "objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "Path"" line?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/path-property-filesystemobject-object

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, oAccess, objShell, ScriptPath, ScriptFile, ScriptFolder, objAccess

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName

Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ScriptFile = objFSO.GetFile(ScriptPath)

ScriptFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(ScriptFile) 

Set objFolder = ScriptFolder


For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtentionName(objFile.Name)) = "accdb" Then
    Set oAccess = objFolder & objFile.Name
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase oAccess

    Dim i
    For i = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.count - 1
    Debug.Print CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name
    If Left(CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name,2) = "I-" Then
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(i).name
    End If

    **Next i**

    Dim z As Integer
    For z = 0 To CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.count - 1
    Debug.Print CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name
    If Left(CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name,2) = "E-" Then
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications(z).name
    End If

    Next z

 Set i = Nothing
 Set z = Nothing

    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

    ObjAccess.Quit
    Set ObjAccess = Nothing
    Set oAccess = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing


Next


Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Ok, I've moved on a little bit and played about with different encoding.
I'm currently using ANSI.

Im now getting an error on Line 31. char 7.

"Next i" for reference.
Unexpected end of Statement.

Any help?

Thanks,